# VM Reboot: Run python flask server and webpack-dev server automatically on system start-up

Tags: python, windows, powershell, azure, windows-server-2012

Every time my VM reboots I need to do two things:

1. Run my Flask server where API is hosted
2. Run the webpack-dev server to serve front-end files

Is there a way in Windows Server where I can execute the above two command prompt commands i.e. `python flaskserver.py` and `npm start` to run automatically at system startup in cases where my VM reboots automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a startup task in Windows Server 2012, we can leverage **Task Scheduler** in **Administrative Tools**. Here are the general steps:

1, Create a file with the command script, i.e.

`cd C:\your_node_app_path
  npm start`

save it as a powershell file, i.e. `startup.ps1`.

2, Click **Create Basic Task** in Task Scheduler.

3, Set a name, click “Next”.

4, Select **when the computer starts** in **Trigger** Tab.

5, Select **Start a program** in **Action** Tab.

6, Type **cmd.exe** in Program/script input, and type the command which will be ran in via cmd.exe, i.e. `powershell –f <your_startup_ps1_file_path>`. Click “next” and “finish”

7, In the **Task Scheduler Library** we can find the task we created above, double click to edit its properties. 
[image]

8, In **General** tab select “Run whether user is logged on or not” , In **Conditions** tab unmark “start the task only if the computer is on AC power” under the **Power** section.
[image]

And here is my test script shown in **action** tab.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes all you need to do is create a batch file with all the commands you wish to execute and then place this file in `Startmenu/Programs/Startup` folder.

Here is your batch file code

```
@echo off
echo "Following process are about to start"
cd/
cd "c:\location\of-my-flask-app\and\npm-start"
python flaskserver.py
npm start
```

Now save it as **"myFile.bat"** and save it in startup folder

Note : correctly specify the path where your flaskserver.py is located